# How best do I implement mysql data into a line of javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, while-loop

I am modifying some javascript for Google maps so that the different pin information is retrieved from my database. If I was to do this with just php it would be like this:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{$title = $row['title']; $desc = $row['desc']; echo 'This '.$title .' and this '. $desc .';}?>
```

If there were 5 rows in the database there will be five lines with 5 different titles and descriptions.
But I have this line of javascript that I would like to be in a while loop:

```
map.addMarkerByLatLng(37.8685, -1.5108, "Sanatario de Terburculosos", createInfo("title goes here",""));
```

How can i write it so that that javascript is in a php while loop or how can i do the javascript equivelant of the php while loop so that i can retrieve multiple rows of lang,lat info each in its own javascript code like above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two code examples you have provided:

```
<?php
$pinTpl = 'map.addMarkerByLatLng( %s , %s , "%s" , createInfo( "%s" , "" ) );';
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){
  echo sprintf( $pinTpl ,
         $row['lat'] ,   # Where 'lat' is the field name for the latitude in DB
         $row['long'] ,  # Where 'long' is the longitude field name in DB
         $row['title'] , # The title
         $row['desc']    # The description
  )."\n";                # A newline, for readability
}
?>
```

Comment: if you start using code like this, you'll be setting yourself up for failure. You're better off doing something like `echo 'var='.json_encode($data).';'` and accessing that variable.

Comment: @ilia choly: I disagree, but am intrigued by your reasoning. What makes you think this is "setting yourself up for failure"?

Comment: because you're generating javascript with php. That's extremely hacky. You could at least have a separate js file for generating and loading all required variables as objects created with json_encode. Finally, the code you're generating is very redundant as opposed to iterating over an object.

Comment: @ilia choly: But it's simple, answers the question with the least amount of reworking, does not add an AJAX call to the process, and provides the OP with a stepping stone towards developing more complex systems (and using more complex systems to do so). I get what you are saying, but still, I disagree with the basis of your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

ajax.php

```
<?php
    $obj = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $obj[] = new array(
            "title" => $row["title"],
            "desc"  => $row["desc"],
            "lat"   => $row["lat"],
            "lon"   => $row["lon"]
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

jquery ajax

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php",function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        map.addMarkerByLatLng(
            data[i].lon, 
            data[i].lat, 
            data[i].description, 
            createInfo(data[i].title,""));
    }
});
```